# While using full page js how to add animations (like slide in left, fade in etc) to div as soon as they are in view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, fullpage.js

I am creating a webpage using full page js (link: 'http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/' )
Now, I want a few divs to display animated effects when they are in view while scrolling. For usual websites, when I am not using fullpage.js it is easily achievable using the following code:

**JQuery:**

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if (isScrolledIntoView('.class') === true) {
        $('.class').addClass('in-view')
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.class {
    opacity: 0;
}
.class.in-view {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

however this is not working while using fullpage.js, can somebody suggest some other way.
I want a div to come sliding in when I reach that particular section/slide.
thank you!

Comment: Can you provide an example? Jsfiddle perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an example within [the examples folder of fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/examples). 
The filename is "callbacks.html".Check it out.

You can make use of fullPage.js [callbacks](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks) to fire them, or even to [the state classes added to the body element](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs) if you want to fire them with CSS.

Check also [this example regarding the fullPage.js callbacks](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/callbacks.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am completely new to the world of coding and all, so I didn't think of checking out the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
isOnScreen = function(ele){
var win = $(window);

var viewport = {
    top : win.scrollTop(),
    left : win.scrollLeft()
};
viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

var element = $("ele");
var bounds = element.offset();

bounds.right = bounds.left + element.outerWidth();
bounds.bottom = bounds.top + element.outerHeight();

return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
```

}

[you can find jsfiddle link here :](http://jsfiddle.net/wN7ah/457/)